# What does it mean to freeze or unfreeze a model?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm going over the fast.ai course on deep learning now, and there's frequent calls to `freeze`/`unfreeze` methods in the lesson notebooks.

The docs are a little sparse on details of what this means, though. The docstrings just read `Freeze up to last layer.` and `Unfreeze entire model.`

Based on my current programming knowledge, my educated guess is that it makes the model im/mutable, so it can be used with the learning rate finder without changing it. But that is still a guess. Very grateful to anyone who can clarify this for me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you guessed at, freezing prevents the weights of a neural network layer from being modified during the backward pass of training. You progressively 'lock-in' the weights for each layer to reduce the amount of computation in the backward pass and decrease training time.

You can unfreeze a model if you decide you want to continue training - an example of this is transfer learning: start with a pre-trained model, unfreeze the weights, then continuing training on a different dataset. When you choose to freeze is a balance between freezing early enough to gain computational speed-up without freezing too early with weights that result in inaccurate predictions.

The original paper is available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04983.pdf), it's a good read.

FREEZEOUT: ACCELERATE TRAINING BY PROGRESSIVELY FREEZING LAYERS by Andrew Brock, Theodore Lim, J.M. Ritchi and Nick Weston.